# Do someting if user does not interact after some time - PHP

Tags: php, api

I`m building a whatsapp bot, the bot is fully operational, but I want to do a API call if user does not interact with the api after some time. I tryed to do with session, but is not working, I tryed the following code.

```
session_start();

//**my bot code**

$minutesBeforeSessionExpire=30;
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > (2))) {

    $data2 = [
        'phone' => $_SESSION['phone'],
        'body' => 'Hello, Andrew!',
    ];
    $json2 = json_encode($data2);
    $options2 = stream_context_create(['http' => [
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
            'content' => $json2
        ]
    ]);
    $result2 = file_get_contents('api_call', false, $options2);
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION   
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data  
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity
```

Comment: What is the problem with that code ? Is not executing at all (at least the last part) ? How are you running that code (cron job) ? Please, add more details

Comment: I did not set any cron, the code is running when the person interact with the whatsapp number

Comment: Sorry, I am lost now, you are saying that you want the BOT to send something to the user when some defined time passed and the user did not interact with it, right ? If that's so, how are you running that code without the intervention of the user ? Are you waiting for magic to happen ? Can you explain that part ?

Comment: I thought that setting a session, after some time the api will send the answer, so I imagine that I`m doing it completely wrong, I must have a cron to do that?

Comment: No problem at all, Mike Robinson answer is correct, this is all server side so it is _reactive_, for making it _proactive_ you will have to use cronjobs or in the case of Laravel, queue jobs or schedule tasks or other similar stuff.

Comment: I see, so I create the cron job to run my code again, it will see the session expiration and run my code?

Comment: Depends on the content of your not-shared `//**my bot code**`, it is still a little more complex than it sounds, I do not know how do you interact with the API, I mean, how do you send something to the user, I do not know Whatsapp API and also, you cannot have sessions on the cron, because you will have to store everyones session somehow (cronjob is "other user" but not actual user, so you would have to store this info in a database or a cache like Redis) so the code reads this source of truth and does something with that user, like reading timeout and sending the message

Comment: Right, so I will have to store the last interaction of the user on my database, after that a another php file do check if that last interaction, and finaly send the mensage. I`m on the right path?

Comment: Yes ! Check jmoreno answer, that is the correct path, search more about what he is talking about !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, "any API" is purely *"server side."* Therefore, it cannot "react" when anyone "fails to reply."  The only thing that it can do is, when presented with [any ...] subsequent request, to say: *"So sorry, too late!"*

The key point being that the response is *reactive,* not *proactive.*

Answer (score 1):

In order to “do something” when a user doesn’t interact, there must be something that interacts with the user.  This is typically either a client side script, websockets, signal R.  It doesn’t just happen naturally, in fact quite the opposite, naturally the server totally forgets about an incoming request as soon as it is done with it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this question, I solved my issue by storing the user last interaction on my db.

After that I created a cron on my cpanel to run the update code, and everything ran as expected.